# nav navbar-nav not available?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Navbars</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

is the code nav navbar-nav not working anymore in bootstrap version 4>?
does this code works only with bootstrap 3?
I took the code for navbar-nav from an old program Order I am not getting wt I am doing wrong any help would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [migration documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/) to figure out the differences between *bootstrap* v3 and v4. There are [couple important changes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#navbar) for `navbar`!

The following would work for *bootstrap4*:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/6a3p7t2r/12/

There are changes for navbar, toggler, nav, navbar-nav, etc. **I strongly encourage you to check out Bootstrap's documentation!**

Comment: just one thing ..how does that sign up and login appeared at right hand side ??

Comment: See `mr-auto` class? That means auto margin right. In bootstrap4, lots of elements are styled as flexbox. In this case, the `navbar-collapse` is displayed as flexbox. Those two `navbar-nav` are the flexbox children. And if you apply margins to a flexbox child, that child will automatically extend its margin to occupy the extra space within the flexbox container in the specified direction. Here since we apply auto margin right, the first `navbar-nav` hence will take up all the extra spaces to the right until it can't, where the second `navbar-nav` is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `Bootstrap 4/4.1x` supports `navbar-nav`

Use `navbar-light/navbar-dark` instead of `navbar-default`. follow this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZFBb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
```

instead of:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">  <!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
```

Now you might noticed the difference between BS3 and BS4. it isn't too much